# rsync error + command not found

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, rsync

I'm trying to pull a project from an AWS server, but for some reason I don't understand, rsync is not working. When I try to run this command:

```
vinicius@Inspiron-5537:~/Desktop/PHP$ rsync --protect-args -aP -e "ssh ubuntu@84.26.56.23 -i ~/Desktop/Projeto.pem" "ubuntu@84.26.56.23:/var/www/projeto/" .
```

I get the following errors:

```
bash: 84.26.56.23: command not found
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: remote command not found (code 127) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.1]
```

but the weird part is that if I ssh the server with

```
ssh ubuntu@84.26.56.23 -i ~/Desktop/Projeto.pem
```

it logs in just fine! Can anybody tell me what is going on? How should I proceed to pull my files from the server. I don't know if it has something to do with, but the `/var/www/projeto/` being owned by root user, but all the users have at least read permission. My client is Ubuntu 16.04, and my server is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
rsync --protect-args -aP -e "ssh -i ~/Desktop/Projeto.pem" "ubuntu@84.26.56.23:/var/www/projeto/" .
```

[man rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)
states

> -e, --rsh=COMMAND           specify the remote shell to use

and

> -e, --rsh=COMMAND
>       This option allows you to choose an alternative remote shell program to use for communication between the local and remote copies
>   of rsync. Typically, rsync is configured to use ssh by default, but
>   you may prefer to use rsh on a local network.
>
> If this option is used
>   with [user@]host::module/path, then the
>       remote shell COMMAND will be used to run an rsync daemon on the remote host, and all data will be transmitted through that remote
>   shell connection, rather than through a direct socket connection to a
>   running rsync daemon on the remote host. See the section lqUSING
>   RSYNC-DAEMON FEATURES VIA A REMOTE-SHELL CONNECTIONrq above.
>
> Command-line arguments are permitted in COMMAND provided that COMMAND
>   is
>       presented to rsync as a single argument. You must use spaces (not tabs or other whitespace) to separate the command and args from each
>   other, and you can use single- and/or double-quotes to preserve spaces
>   in an argument (but not backslashes). Note that doubling a
>   single-quote inside a single-quoted string gives you a single-quote;
>   likewise for double-quotes (though you need to pay attention to which
>   quotes your shell is parsing and which quotes rsync is parsing). Some
>   examples:
>
> CW -e 'ssh -p 2234'
>
> CW -e 'ssh -o "ProxyCommand nohup ssh firewall nc -w1 %h %p"' (Note that ssh users can alternately customize site-specific connect
>   options in their .ssh/config file.)
>
> You can also choose the remote shell program using the RSYNC_RSH
>   environment variable, which accepts the same range of values as -e.
>
> See also the --blocking-io option which is affected by this option.

so the extra ubuntu@84.26.56.23 is what broke it.